# Symfony 5.1 creating extension with services

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a config for an extension which will give me 1 service with all dependencies injected but so far I was unable to do it. My steps were this to follow those steps in this web page https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html but I still get an error that I don't have service

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Command\ParserConfigAutoCreationCommand": argument "$nominatimGeocode" of method "__construct()" references class "XYZ\Service\NominatimGeocode" but no such service exists.
```

my services.yml file:

```
    services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:
            Geocoder\Provider\Provider $nominatimProvider: '@bazinga_geocoder.provider.nominatim'
            Geocoder\Provider\Provider $googleProvider: '@bazinga_geocoder.provider.google'

    XYZ\Service\NominatimGeocode:
        arguments: [ '@bazinga_geocoder.provider.nominatim' ]
```

and my GeoCodeExtension.php file:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace XYZ\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration.
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class GeoCodeExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
//        $configuration = new Configuration();
//        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

do I need to add additional files or something?

EDIT:

```
class NominatimGeocode
{
    /**
     * @var \Geocoder\Provider\Provider
     */
    private $nominatimProvider;
    private $checkPostCode = false;

    /**
     * Geo Nominatim constructor.
     *
     * @param \Geocoder\Provider\Provider $nominatimProvider
     */
    public function __construct(Provider $nominatimProvider)
    {
        $this->nominatimProvider = $nominatimProvider;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

so I'm injecting it with right param name.

Comment: So XYZ is your bundle namespace?  Are you loading your bundle in config/bundles.php? Does your extension get called? Is your XYZ source code under your application's src or is it completely separate? Here is a [working example](https://github.com/cerad/bundle) of a simple explorer-bundle showing everything wired together.

Comment: @Cerad I'll check it later, thank you for showing it to me

Answer (score 0):

Your class should inject the `Geocoder\Provider\Provider $nominatimProvider` dependency if you want [type binding](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type) to work.

Mind the variable's name must match the one in the `bind` section too.

Your is totally different:

```
XYZ\Service\NominatimGeocode $nominatimGeocode
```